# How to implement Google's recaptcha from within a Cocoon pipeline

Tags: java, apache-cocoon, recaptcha

I would like to ask if is there any examples on how to implement Google's recaptcha from Apache-cocoon? Most examples I've seen in the web for Java are using JSP.

I've tried using CaptchaReader from [https://cocoon.apache.org](https://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/blocks/captcha/1.0/687_1_1.html) but unfortunately it is using `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg` which is not supported in Java 7 (from what I've read).

Comment: What do you mean, "implement Google's recaptcha"?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I would like to implement it like this: (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/java), but I'm not using jsp, I'm using cocoon.